# How translate an object taken from Api with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I have these object taken from an Api

```
<div v-if="getError">
      <div v-for="(_errors, key) in getError">
       
        <b-alert show variant="danger" v-for="error in _errors">
          <h2>{{key.replace('contract_data.','')}} :</h2>
        <li>{{error}}</li>  </b-alert>
      
      </div>
    </div>
```

my question is how to translate these? i tried to do this:

```
<b-alert show variant="danger" v-for="error in _errors">
          <h2>{{$t('vue.'+key).replace('contract_data.','')}} :</h2>
        <li>{{$t('error')}}</li>  </b-alert>
```

but it doesn't works

Comment: HI, I think that you are replacing (removing) "contract_data" AFTER the translation occurs... I suggest to put the replace inside the $t function parenthesis. eg. `$t('vue.'+key.replace(contract_data', ''))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as @Seididieci mentioned on comment

```
$t('vue.'+key.replace('contract_data.',''))
```

Answer (score -2):

const EXTERNAL_OBJECT = reactive({ name:"Bob",
list:[{name:"Ivan"}] });

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).